# A bash script that takes a .c filename as an argument and then executes that file

Tags: c, bash

So I'm a grader at my college and I'm trying to create a bash script that reads in a compiled c program as an argument and then runs a bunch of tests on the program that tests a bunch of different scenarios so that I don't have to run the program with different inputs each time.

This is what I have

```
#!/bin/bash
#test.sh
read studentFile


$studentFile "1011" "2" "10"
echo "11"
./$studentFile "1011" "2" "16"
echo "B"
./$studentFile "1010" "2" "8"
echo "12"
./$studentFile "FA" "16" "2" 
echo "11111010" 
./$studentFile "12" "8" "2"
echo "1010"
```

etc. 
(the print out following each execution is the right answer that the program should return and match)

Whenever I run this with one a compiled c program as the input
ie

```
./test.sh studentfilename
```

it returns this error

```
./test.sh: line 8: ./: Is a directory
```

for each line where I try to run the program.

I've tested the input file and made sure it worked before trying to input it into this testing script.

Does anyone know how to take a file as input and run it?

Any help much appreciated thanks!!

Comment: Not related to the main problem, you will have to compile the source file before executing it in typical environment.

Comment: Hmmm... just the title is confusing and the question says that the bash script reads in a *compiled c program*.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are invoking the script with the compiled program as an argument, you need to use

```
studentFile=$1
```

not

```
read studentFile
```

Comment: Thanks that was the problem!

Answer (score 2):

you want to pass the file name via command line argument, so you have to use variables like `$1` to get the name.

Try `studentFile=$1` instead of `read studentFile`.